# mysql_real_escape_string and PDO no connection in mvc pattern

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, mysql-real-escape-string

I have created my own mvc pattern based on the codeigniter framework style. My problem now is that i want to prevent from SQL injection, and for that purpose i would like to use mysql_real_escape_string(). But for when i use it, it keeps erroring since it apparently don't have a the "link/source" to the database?

I get the php error:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in
>   /hsphere/local/home/../dev/simple_blog/models/users_model.php on line
>   8
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be
>   established in
>   /hsphere/local/home/../dev/simple_blog/models/users_model.php on line
>   8

I don't quite understand why though, since i can get stuff in and out of my DB but for some reason i can't protect it???

Here is my function giving the error

```
public function getUserByName($username){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->db_table." WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1";
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($q->rowCount() > 0){
      foreach($q->fetch() as $key => $row){
        $data[$key] = $row;
      }
      return $data;
    }
  }
```

As you can see I use mysql_real_escape_string() at the top, and then later on, do query stuff. Anyone know why this don't work and if yes, how would i fix it?

NOTE: Im not a shark to PDO, and $this->db is the PDO class.

Comment: Did you connect to a database using `mysql_connect()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `mysql_real_escape_string` you'll need to connect to the database server first, using the MySQL Functions, which you probably don't have done.

You are mixing up two completely different PHP extensions: [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)!

Also, you don't need to escape strings, when using PDO prepared statements, that's done via PDO for you.

An example using PDO:

```
$userDataStmt = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->db_table . ' WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');
$userDataStmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$userDataStmt->execute();
if(!$userDataStmt->rowCount() <= 0)
{
    $result = $userDataStmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, never though of it that way... I never though of PDO doing it for me, doh! But thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. PDO will escape for you if you use prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->db_table." WHERE username=:user LIMIT 1";
$stmt->bind(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

PDO uses (I believe) the mysqli library behind the scenes. mysql_escape_real_string uses the mysql library (note the **lack** of an `i`). Both libraries have completely independent connection pools, so unless you establish a throw-away link with `mysql_connect()`, you cannot use mysql_real_escape_string anyways, as it requires an active DB connection.

Answer (score 0):

The PDO version is `PDO::quote()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

So in your case it would be

```
$username = $this->db->quote($username);
```

However, most recommend using PDO prepared statements for avoiding SQL Injection in PDO. See
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php